# Is there a Ruby shortcut for calling the same name of a method chain?

Tags: ruby

Say I have

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

p B.superclass.superclass.superclass # => BasicObject
```

Instead of calling .superclass 3 times, is there some way I can specify something like a repeat operator which will basically say call this method x times?

Comment: Good Innovative Question Friend(*+1*).......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it is done

```
3.times.reduce(B) {|a, _| a.superclass } # => BasicObject
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to send it, as long as it is nowhere private.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: I reformatted your code a little bit. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Actually, I wanted to ask, I noticed quite a few chaps here use the style that you reformatted it into, which manual of style is it?

Comment: The first thought was also about reduce. But then I couldn't think of a collection to apply it to. Forgot about `times`. I need rest.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks, interesting reading. I've been using [this one](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml), but with a dose of creativity.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I made it my one.. I forgot to use `:send`. I was using `send`.. So I was getting error.. :)

Answer (score 4):

I made it as below :

```
([:superclass]*3).inject(B,:send)
# => BasicObject
```

Comment: Regarding the style, don't you think it's crammed with no whitespaces?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I didn't understand what you mean? :(

Comment: @BorisStitnicky If anything wrong in my post.. you can edit it.. I have no problem. My company firewall not allowing me to open the link,you just given.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing existing (that I know of). But here, I built one for you. :)

```
class A
end

class B < A
end

class Object
  def call_repeatedly(sym, n)
    res = self
    n.times { res = res.send(sym)}
    res
  end
end

B.call_repeatedly(:superclass, 3) # => BasicObject
```